# I am looking for a script which will take IP addresses from a text fill and ping all of them

Tags: python-3.x

This is the code which is working, which creates two different files with the list of IPs which are reachable and unreachable, I am looking to add a serial number before the iP to save the IP is in below format within each file:
1. x.x.x.x
2. x.x.x.x
etc..

```
 #Create list from a file with IPs
    ip_list = open("E:\\Python-Scripts\\IPs.txt").read().splitlines()

 #Remove duplicate IPs from the list
 ip_list = list(set(ip_list))

 # Ping ips from the list
 import os
 for ip_address in ip_list:
 response = os.system("ping -n 1 " + ip_address)


 #and then check the response...
if response == 0:
        with open('E:\\Python-Scripts\\ping_reachable.txt', 'a') as 
the_file:
the_file.write('{} " is reachable\n"'.format(ip_address))
            #the_file.write('{1}.{0}  is reachable\n'.format(ip_address, 
    count))

    else:
        with open('E:\\Python-Scripts\\ping_unreachable.txt', 'a') as 
    the_file:
                the_file.write('{} " is not reachable\n"'.format(ip_address))
            #the_file.write('{1}.{0}  is not reachable\n'.format(ip_address, 
    count))
```

Comment: Where are your serial numbers?

Comment: This code would not run at all as posted, due to indentation problems - you need to make sure that what you post is *exactly* what you're trying to run.  (Paste the code, select all of it, hit Control-K.)  You also need to clarify what exactly is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the script which is working for python in windows, hope this may help any network engineer:

> ```
> #Create list from a file with IPs
> #ip_list = open("E:\\Python-Scripts\\IPs.txt").read().splitlines()
>
> #Remove duplicate IPs from the list
> #ip_list = list(set(ip_list))
>
> # Ping ips from the list
> #import os
> #for ip_address in ip_list:
> # response = os.system("ping -n 1 " + ip_address)
>
>
> #and then check the response...
> # if response == 0:
> #         with open('E:\\Python-Scripts\\ping_reachable.txt', 'a') as the_file:
> #                 the_file.write('{} " is reachable\n"'.format(ip_address))
>           #the_file.write('{1}.{0}  is reachable\n'.format(ip_address, count))
>
> # else:
> #         with open('E:\\Python-Scripts\\ping_unreachable.txt', 'a') as 
>    the_file:
> #             the_file.write('{} " is not reachable\n"'.format(ip_address))
>       #the_file.write('{1}.{0}  is not reachable\n'.format(ip_address, count))
>
> ip_list = open("E:\\Python-Scripts\\IPs.txt").read().splitlines()
>
> ip_list = list(set(ip_list)) import os i=1 j=1 reach=[] not_reach=[]
> #for n, ip_address in enumerate(ip_list): for ip_address in ip_list:
>     response = os.system("ping -n 1 " + ip_address)
>     if response == 0:
>         reach.append('{}. {} is reachable\n'.format(i,ip_address))
>         i+=1
>     else:
>         not_reach.append('{}. {} is not reachable\n'.format(j,ip_address))
>         j+=1
>
> with open('E:\\Python-Scripts\\ping_reachable.txt', 'a') as f:
>     for i in reach:
>         f.write(i)
>
> with open('E:\\Python-Scripts\\ping_unreachable.txt', 'a') as  f:
>     for i in not_reach:
>         f.write(i)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but seems like your ping command is wrong.
Ping should have `-c` instead of `-n` if you want to ping only once.

```
response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + ip_address)
```

Comment: I am using this script in windows so used -n instead of -c